# How to give a custom UITableViewCell context of what it is editing?

Tags: ios, swift

So right now I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains a `UITextField`. The `UITextField` is not user interaction enabled while the cell is. When you tap the cell, the textField becomes user interaction enabled and then becomes first responder. The `UITextFieldDelegate` is implemented in the custom `UITableViewCell` class. My view controller has a store of todos, and I want the custom `UITableViewCell` to know which todo it is editing, and then update the model and view when it is done editing when it's delegate method is called. How do I implement this?

Comment: you can make the the customcell to be the delegate of textField not the viewcontroller

Comment: @WilsonXJ yes this is what I did. But then how do i keep the context in the custom cell and let the view controller know its done editing?

Comment: yes you can use callback or delegate

Comment: The most simplest way will be to pass the whole array and the index of the currently selected object and access it there but i don't that's a good idea.How about if you set the delegate on controller and edit it there it will save you from having scattered code, not having multiple copies of the array and also you don't even need a custom protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class file for your `UITableViewCell` you can declare a protocol like:

```
protocol TextFieldUpdateDelegate {
    func textFieldHasChanged(textField: UITextField)
}
```

Then give you `UITableViewCell` class an instance variable:

```
var textFieldUpdateDelegate: TextFieldUpdateDelegate?
```

When you handle the UITextFieldDelegate methods you can need to call back to the delegate similar to:

```
    if (textFieldUpdateDelegate != nil) {
        textFieldUpdateDelegate!.textFieldHasChanged(textField)
    }
```

Your table view controller needs to do a few things:

```
// declare that it implements the protocol
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController: TextFieldUpdateDelegate


// Actually implement the method
func textFieldHasChanged(textField: UITextField) {
   // Do your magic
}

// Make sure to set the delegate on your table view cells
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCell") as! YourTableViewCell
cell.textFieldUpdateDelegate = self
```

Hopefully that's enough to help you get the pieces all connected.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the answer! I actually figured it out from here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/ before you answered, but I really appreciate. going to accept this